# Are all hypotenuses irrational if the shorter sides are integers?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Is it sufficient to say that providing the shorter two sides of a right triangle can be expressed as integers that work out to equal the value of the hypotenuse, then the value of the hypotenuse must be irrational?  For example, suppose I wish to prove that $\sqrt 5$ is irrational, if the shorter sides are 1 and 2 then the length of the hypotenuse $\sqrt 5$ must be irrational.  Please tell me if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Have you heard of Pythagorean triples? Such as 3,4,5

Comment: Can't say I have.

Comment: @MichaelLee Well, it should answer your question. $3^2+4^2=5^2$.

Comment: $$5^2+12^2=13^2, \;8^2+15^2=17^2,\;161^2+240^2=289^2,...$$

Comment: Oh! Now I follow you!  If the sides consist of 3,4,5 then the hypotenuse is indeed a rational number.  I can't thank you all enough for helping me here, it would have taken me ages to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

take two integer numbers $m>n>0$, than:
$$
a=m^2-n^2 \qquad b=2mn \qquad c=m^2+n^2
$$
are integers such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (which is easy to prove). These are called the Pythagorean triples.